# Specify field to be rendered in the django admin

Tags: python, django

I use the default `User` class from `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`. In the user creation when the user is created I set the username field to a random hash. When I use the model in ManyToMany field and use it in the Django admin then the random hash is rendered in the select box. Is there a way to specify the field to be taken from the model to be displayed in the select box so that I can specify the model as ManyToMany field and use the email to be rendered in the django admin form.

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    group = models.ManyToManyField(Group, null=True)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True)
```

Is there a field like the display_name that can be passed to the model field so that the appropriate field can be taken from the ManyToMany model for rendering. I am using Django 1.5.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to do something like this,

```
class TestModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=[ (user.id, user.email) for user in User.objects.all()])
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        fields = ('user','group')

class TestModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TestModelAdminForm
```

Comment: Many thanks. I think the `o` in list comprehension should be `user`. I couldn't edit the same due to character limit. @Anoop